# Display A Tooltip On MouseOver HandsonTable Header

Tags: mouseover, handsontable

Handsontable has an option to display tooltips in the headers.
https://docs.handsontable.com/pro/1.1.1/demo-header-tooltips.html

Is there another way to do it that doesn't require the "Pro" version?

Perhaps [afterOnCellMouseOver](http://docs.handsontable.com/0.19.0/Hooks.html#event:afterOnCellMouseOver)?

I also have [Angular-UI Tooltip](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/versioned-docs/0.13.4/#/tooltip) in the project so perhaps that could overlay somehow.

Comment: did you have any progress? this is what I tried but does not seem to work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37645434/handsontable-bootstrap-tooltip-for-column-header/37666661?noredirect=1#comment62846564_37666661

Answer (score 6):

You can directly put the html code adding the tooltip while defining your colHeaders :

```
colHeaders: ["Trend", "Year", '<span title="External Color"> External Color </span>', '<span title="Internal Color"> Internal Color </span>'],
```

See a working example in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/trc3639h/2/)

It's up to you if you want to use customize tooltip like bootstrap or Angular or even fully customize by you, but your Angular-UI Tooltip already included in your project should not prevent you to do the above.

Comment: Why was this not accepted as the answer? Extremely simple and works perfectly. Thanks!